# How to set the duratiion of a song in C #

Tags: c#, web-applications, soundplayer

I have an application that plays a particular song for a specified time, as the result of a select.

I can already play the songs, but I can not set a time duration.

```
    public void PlaySound()
    {
        int i = 0;

        foreach (string musicFile in musicFiles)
        {
            Thread thrStopMusic = new Thread(ThreadTimer);
            player.SoundLocation = musicFile;
            musicExecuteTime = GetMusicDuration[i];
            player.Play();
            thrStopMusic.Start();
            thrStopMusic.Abort();
            i++;
        }
    }

 public void ThreadTimer()
    {
       Thread.Sleep(musicExecuteTime * 1000);
       StopSound();
    }
```

im using SoundPlayer class.

Comment: What do you mean by i can not set a time duration? What is it exactly you want to achieve?

Comment: I need to start with a SoundROund PLAY (), and after a certain set time in seconds to a STOP (). I tried doing this with thread, using sleep. But do not think it worked very well.

Comment: Check the answers below. Basically what you do is start a new thread that does nothing and just sleep this thread instead of the "main" thread you are in. Just call the Thread.Sleep(time*1000) in your main loop :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

i think you can just do something like this. `Play()` uses a new thread to play the file so you should just need to 'pause' your thread for an amount of time before invoking `Stop()`.

```
public void PlaySound()
{
    int i = 0;

    foreach (string musicFile in musicFiles)
    {
        player.SoundLocation = musicFile;
        player.Play();
        Thread.Sleep(1000 * GetMusicDuration[i])
        player.Stop();
        i++;
    }
}
```

Comment: This works, but my application is inactive. I have a dashboard that shows real-time information. I'm doing a play call in Page_Load should be done elsewhere?

Comment: You should run playsound as above in another thread. [here](http://ideone.com/FQkwoh) is an example that you should addapt/cleanup.

Answer (score 2):

Maybe i did not understand your intent correctly, but why do you even use a thread for your timing (also i guess `StopSound()`is not the appropriate method to call)? Why not just:

```
...
player.Play();
Thread.Sleep(musicExecuteTime * 1000);
player.Stop();
...
```

Comment: I'm using a method because I have a graph in real time running in the background. If you use this code ALL my system will hang for 15 seconds

Comment: If the files in `musicFiles`should be played consecutively maybe you should move the whole `PlaySound`code to a thread so your main thread is not blocked.